# Addition Assignment confusion, again JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[According to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment), the Addition Assignment operator
adds the value of the right operand to a variable
and assigns the result to the variable. The types of the two operands determine the behavior of the addition. 
Here's the behavior of the addition:

- If both expressions are *numeric*, then add.
- If both expressions are *strings*, then concatenate.
- If expression is *numeric* and the other is a *string* , then concatenate.

Basically, `text+=i` is the same as `text = text + i`; that is a fact.

Ok, if the above is true, then *why* in Code Version 2 below when I variable-ize  the string `"The number is "` to the variable `text`, 
doesn't it write the string each time with the new number as code version 1 does?

And for the answer **I don't want another way to write** it. I need to figure out why it doesn't work the same way if `text+=i` is the same as `text = text + i`.

I'm getting better at JavaScript every day, but believe it or not this simple `+=` is holding me back from further understanding it because too many examples are using `+=`.

Here is the Code Version 1:

```html
 <h1>JavaScript Loops</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Here is the Code Version 2 with var `text` variable-ized with the string `"The number is "`:

```html
<h1>JavaScript Loops</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text ="The number is ";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text = text + i + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Comment: TL;DR???? When you add a string and a number, you ***always*** end up with a string, no matter what, ***always***. If you add a number ... and a number, you get a number. The second you add a string into the mix, and a string is anything with quotes around it, you get ... a string.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/24fc9p1b/

Comment: def understand that part thats not what im asking...im ASKING if a+=b is same as a = a +b why is my code not working the same with text+=i and text = text + i

Comment: Because in the second one `text` is something different each time you go through the loop, whereas `"The number is "` is always the same. You are *not* performing the same operation.  If you wanted the same thing, then the second one would need to be `text = text + "The number is " + i + "<br>";` without assigning `var text ="The number is ";` to begin.

Comment: Yes, those would be the same. But, in one example you have `The number is` inside the loop, so it adds it multiple times, while in the other example it's outside the loop, is only added once.

Comment: what difference does it make if its inside the loop...the string should still behave the same only difference is its a variable now being called INTO the loop instead of a naked string in the LOOP..thats the part thats confusing me

Comment: The string `"The number is "` inside the loop is always constant. It always gets added to `text` in version 1 of the code. In version 2 of the code there is no constant that is added each time. In version 2, you just have the `"The number is "` once, and only once.  Now, if instead of `var text ="The number is ";` you used `var numberIsText ="The number is ";` and then used `text = text + numberIsText + i + "<br>";` it would be the same as what you have in version 1.  Part of your confusion is that your version 2 changes that line more than just changing `text +=` to `text = text +`.

Answer (score 3):

You are writing different code.

`a = a + b` is indeed the same as `a += b`.

```
var text = "";
text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
```

Is the same as:

```
var text = "";
text = text + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
```

But it's not the same as:

```
var text = "The number is ";
text = text + i + "<br>";
```

Which is what you had.

Comment: and see thats the problem HOW is it not....only difference is that string is  a variable now

Comment: It's different because adding an empty string with another string will always produce the other string.. Where as if you add a non-empty string with a non-empty string it will produce a string totally different from either string.

Comment: Think of it this way. You know `5 + 5` is 10. If you loop the operation two times, you end up with `5 + 5 + 5` which is 15. Likewise you can have `7+3` which is also 10, but once you start looping it you'll be getting `7 + 3 + 3` which is 13.

Comment: @GullyBoy, Maybe it will help to equate the string constants to single letters. You are trying to identify the difference between using `text +=` and `text = text +`, but what you wrote in version 1 is `text += N + i + B` whereas in version 2 you used `text = text + i + B` (without `N`). If you want to directly compare them you need to use `text = text + N + i + B` compared to `text += N + i + B`.

Answer (score 1):

For a question like this, it can be very helpful to use **console.log** to see what is happening.

```
var text ="";
var i;
console.log("First approach");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    console.log("Iteration: "+i+" Text: "+text);
}

console.log("Second approach");
text ="The number is ";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text = text + i + "<br>";
    console.log("Iteration: "+i+" Text: "+text);
}
```

[image: First and second approach]
The code runs differently because in the first case you concatenate the entire string of "The number is ..." and in the second case, you initialize the string with "The number is " and then only concatenate the digits.

Comment: This would be much better if the third approach did not change the pattern of appending to the `text` variable.  In other words, show code that produces the same output as the first approach, not something totally different. All you needed to do was keep it as `text += stext + i + "<br>";` (which would help it be focused on `+=`, which was the OP's belief as to what his confusion is)

Comment: exactly @makyen

Comment: The question was complicated by the loop.  On the first iteration, both **text += "The number is" + i** and **text = text + i** execute as expected, it is when the loop continues that the output differs.  I added the third approach to illustrate that.

Comment: Problem is your 3rd does not result in the same thing as the 1st. You have changed from the output being the resulting `text` which is assigned to `.innerHTML = text;` to showing the output as successive `console.log()` calls. While the `console.log()` calls can illustrate what is happening, they are not the point of the code. The point was to have the text from all of the iterations be in a single variable which is displayed in the DOM. 3rd does something quite different resulting in it not doing a good job of illustrating the non-difference between `text +=` and `text = text +`.

Comment: @Makyen - I removed the third approach.